# Увеличение числа для того, чтобы оно стало кратно 16

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Допустим, есть число `102`. Как узнать, на сколько его нужно увеличить, чтоб оно стало кратным `16`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Для конкретного случая кратности числу 16 можно использовать битовую арифметику для взятия модуля:

```
int p = 102;
int needAdd = -p & 0xf;
```

---

В общем случае вам нужен остаток (в Эйлеровском смысле, положительный). К сожалению, оператор `%` в языке C# [не очень хорош](/q/229375/10105) для отрицательных значений аргумента, поэтому нам придётся написать свой:

```
public static int Modulo(int p, int q)
{
    q = Math.Abs(q);
    var result = p % q;
    if (result < 0)
        result += q;
    return result;
}
```

Имея правильный остаток, задача тривиальна:

```
int p = 102;
int q = 16;
int needAdd = Modulo(-p, q);
```

Код не зависит от знаков чисел `p`, `q` (только бы `q` не было нулём).

---

Для пуристов: (*needAdd* + *p*) ≡ (−*p* + *p*) ≡ 0 (mod *q*), а по построению, *needAdd* ∈ [0, *q*).

Comment: Наверно автору все же нужно увеличить число, а не узнать остаток.

Comment: @KromStern: `p += needAdd;`?

Comment: Да, так это станет ответом на вопрос.

Comment: @KromStern: Не согласен. Цитирую вопрос: _Как узнать, на сколько его нужно увеличить..._.

Comment: Согласен. Но и остаток тут не при чем.

Comment: @KromStern: Ну, исходя из решения, вполне себе причём. (Переписал решение, оно теперь работает с любыми знаками.)

Answer (score 12):

Самый банальный способ:
102 делим на 16, получаем частное(6) и остаток(6). Проверяем, равен ли остаток нулю. Если равен, тогда мы нашли наше число. Если нет, тогда берём частное, прибавляем к нему единицу. Затем умножаем на 16 и получаем `16*7=112`. Теперь из результата(112), вычитаем начальное число(102) и имеем, что исходное число нужно увеличить на 10.

Comment: зачем так длинно? остаток равен шести, а 16 минус шесть будет 10.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, просто первое, что пришло в голову. Ваше решение лучше, безусловно

Comment: Толковое объяснение, как раз для новичка, и без заумностей с битами  и циклами.

Answer (score 11):

```
am = (a + 0x0FL) & ~0x0FL; // ближайшее сверху число, кратное 16
d = am - a;                // разница
```

Comment: что такое `L` ?

Comment: L - суффикс для указания long констант.

Comment: В каком ЯП принята такая конвернция? В php и js это отсутствует.

Comment: C/C++. Но оно здесь не особо нужно, это я из-за внутренней паранойи привык вставлять, чтобы бытовая константа ожидаемым (для меня) образом битого расширилась до long.

Answer (score 9):

Посмотрим в глаза битам! : )

У чисел кратных 16 младшие 4 бита – нули:

```
 0: 0000 0000
16: 0001 0000
32: 0010 0000
```

Чтобы любое число увеличить до кратного 16, надо прибавить "1" в позициях, где сейчас нули и ещё 1:

```
11:   0000 1011 - только третий бит = "0"
  добавить 0100 - "1" для третьего бита
  добавить 0001 - и ещё +1, чтобы все младшие биты обнулились.
-------------
не хватало 0100 (это 4) и ещё 1 = итого +5

22:   0001 0110 - нули в первом и четвертом битах
  добавить 1001 (это 9)
  добавить 0001 (единицу)
---------------
    сумма: 1010 (это десять)
```

**Вычислить** необходимое увеличение можно тоже битовыми операциями:

**1)** от исходного числа интерсуют только младшие 4 бита. Битовая операция «И» оставит только те биты, которые =1 в обоих операндах:

```
 исходное число:  0101 1100
маска мл. 4 бит:  0000 1111
---------------------------
  результат «И»:  0000 1100
```

**2)** младшие биты надо инвертировать операцией «НЕ»

```
1100
«НЕ»
----
0011
```

**3)** прибавить единицу:

```
 0011  = 3
+0001  = 1
 ----
 0100  = 4
```

Значит, к исходному числу `0101 1100` (92) надо прибавить `0000 0100` (4), чтобы получить 96, которое, видимо, кратно 16.

Comment: Я удивлен, что так много откликнулись на такой простой вопрос и столько развернутых ответов
Жаль, не могу отметить как решение сразу несколько ответов

Answer (score 8):

Следующее кратное 16 число:
- Добавляем 16-1 - это число, остаточк от деления которого на 16 равен -1.
- Целочисленно делим на 16 - получаем округлённый вверх результат деления оригинального числа на 16
- Умножаем на 16 - получаем число не меньшее исходного и кратное 16

```
Math.floor((102+15) / 16) * 16
```

Ну и в виде функции для любых чисел:

```
function calc(x, m) {
  return Math.floor((x+m-1) / m) * m;
}
```

Чтобы узнать, насколько увеличить, надо вычесть из получившегося числа оригинальное.

Answer (score 7):

Псевдокод:

```
исходное_число = 102
кратное_число = 16
частное = 6

если остаток_от_деления(исходное_число) == 0
    возвращаем исходное_число
иначе
    возвращаем (частное + 1) * кратное_число - исходное_число
```

Код на Си:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input_number = 29;
    int multiple = 16;
    int quotient = input_number / multiple;
    int answer = 0;

    if (input_number % multiple == 0) {
        answer = input_number;
    } else {
        answer = (quotient + 1) * multiple - input_number;
    }

    printf("%u\n", answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Я бы делал так:
Делил данное число на 16. Откидал бы дробовую часть, добавлял единицу , умножал на 16 и отнимал число, которые было дано. 
Выглядит это так: 102/16 = 6,375. +1 = 7. 7*16 = 112. 112-102 = 10. Ответ >> 10

Answer (score 4):

при целочисленном делении (положительных чисел) `делимого` на `делитель` получается `частное` и `остаток`.
`искомое` число будет результатом вычитания `остатка` из `делителя`.

1. если в используемом языке есть `функция` или `оператор` получения `остатка` от целочисленного деления, то:

```
искомое = делитель - функция ( делимое, делитель )
искомое = делитель - ( делимое оператор делитель )
```

2. если же в используемом языке есть только `функция` или `оператор` получения `частного` от целочисленного деления, то:

```
искомое = делитель - ( делимое - делитель * функция ( делимое, делитель ) )
искомое = делитель - ( делимое - делитель * ( делимое оператор делитель ) )
```

3. а если нет ни того ни другого, но есть `оператор` (обычного) деления и `функция` округления, то:

```
искомое = делитель - ( делимое - делитель * функция ( делимое оператор делитель ) )
```

4. но если в используемом языке нет ни того ни другого ни третьего, то можно обойтись вычитанием и сравнением. алгоритм на абстрактном языке:

```
если делимое > 0 и делитель > 0

число = делимое

  пока число >= 0
    число = число - делитель
  конец цикла

  искомое = -число

конец условия
```

Comment: Это пройдёт не для всех языков, т. к. разные языки имеют разное представление о том, что такое `%` для отрицательных чисел. (Смотрите, например, таблицу [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation).)

Comment: спасибо, добавил оговорку.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 102;    
m = n%16 ? 16-n%16 : 0;
```

Comment: Минус не мой, но: ваш код не работает для отрицательных `n`, и по модулю этого ничем не отличается от моего ответа.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо за содержательный комментарий.